# What's the best way to add HTML dynamically with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, label

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="dynamicRadioButtons">



</div>
```

Using jQuery I'd like to append a radio button with corresponding label to the above div.  An example of the HTML I'd like to append is as follows:

```
<input type="radio" id="dynamicRadio" name="radio" /><label for="dynamicRadio">My Label</label> <br>
```

So, lets say I have a function that's called when I click something and takes the parameters id (which is the id of the radio button to be created) and labelText (which is the text of the label to be created), I want to be able to do something like this:

```
function OnClick(id, labelText){

    // create a new radio button using supplied parameters
    var $newRadioBtn = $('<input />').attr({type="radio", id=id, name="radio"});

    // create a new radio button using supplied parameters
    // TODO - set the value of the label to parameter: labelText
    var $newLabel = $('<label />').attr({for=id});

    // TODO - append the new radio button and label to the div and then append <br>...
    $('#dynamicRadioButtons').append(/* The elements I want to append */);    
}
```

Can someone help me with my TODO bits please?  I was following an example [as per this page](http://techbrij.com/445/add-dynamic-form-elements-textbox-button-radio-checkbox) but just don't know enough about jQuery to add the label etc.  Also is this the best way to dynamically add HTML elements?

Comment: I had a mess about on jsfiddle and came up with this solution which is enough for me to keep working with but is this the best approach?  http://jsfiddle.net/uNNMr/881/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your label around the form element, which means you don't have to be quite so verbose.

```
<label><input type="radio" id="dynamicRadio" name="radio" />
    My Label
</label>
<br />
```

And you can create it like this:

```
function OnClick(id, labelText) {

    // create a new radio button using supplied parameters
    var newRadio = $('<input />').attr({
        type: "radio", id: id, name: id
    });

    // create a new radio button using supplied parameters
    var newLabel = $('<label />').append(newRadio).append(labelText);

    // append the new radio button and label
    $('#dynamicRadioButtons').append(newLabel).append('<br />');
}
```

I have used the supplied id for the name and id, otherwise all radios would have a name of "radio". You might also want to rename `OnClick` as there are build in event handlers called `onclick` and it might cause confusion.

Here is an example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/Kak5t/)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!  Good point about the method name OnClick - I just typed it absentmindedly as an example.