# jQuery buttonset refresh not working as I'd expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, refresh, jquery-ui-button

OK - I have a function which I call to dynamically add a radio button [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287266/whats-the-best-way-to-add-html-dynamically-with-jquery).  This is the full function:

```
    // function used to create a new radio button
    function createNewRadioButton(
            selector,
            newRadioBtnId,
            newRadioBtnName,
            newRadioBtnText){

        // create a new radio button using supplied parameters
        var newRadioBtn = $('<input />').attr({
            type: "radio", id: newRadioBtnId, name: newRadioBtnName
        });

        // create a new label and append the new radio button
        var newLabel = $('<label />').append(newRadioBtn).append(newRadioBtnText);

        // add the new radio button and refresh the buttonset
        $(selector).append(newLabel).append('<br />').buttonset("refresh");
    }
```

So if I were to call the above function with the following code I would expect another radio button to be added underneath the radio buttons already contained in the div '#radioX' (assuming there is a div with id radioX containing radio buttons):

```
            // create a new radio button using the info returned from server
            createNewRadioButton(
                    '#radioX', // Radio button div id
                    product.Id, // Id
                    product.Id, // Name
                    product.Name // Label Text
            );
```

Given that on document ready, I tell jQuery to create me a buttonset out of the radio buttons contained in #radioX like so: `$( "#radioX" ).buttonset();`, why doesn't the call to `$("#radioX").buttonset("refresh")` in the function createNewRadioButton refresh the list of radio buttons?

The result that I see after a call to createNewRadioButton is made is a new label with the desired text is added but no new radio button.  So instead of a nice new jQuery radio button sitting underneath whatever was already there, I see just a new label with text equivelant to product.Name (in the given example).

I've also noticed this warning output in firebug after a call is made to createNewRadioButton - could this have anything to do with it?

```
reference to undefined property $(this).button("widget")[0]
```

**EDIT**

[Here's a screenshot of what I expected to happen:](http://postimage.org/image/ui05r8u0x/)

[Here's a screenshot of what happens](http://postimage.org/image/d8ycd1bqd/)

Comment: `refresh` method refreshes the state of the buttons (if the value was changed programmatically), it does not re-create the buttonset ([doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#method-refresh))

Comment: Ah! OK - so if I wanted to recreate the buttonset I would need to destroy it and then recreate it?

Comment: Actually `refresh` works, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake. Actually the `refresh` method is taking good care of added radio elements at runtime.

The markup you are generating in `createNewRadioButton()` is I think not compatible with what the plugin expects.

You create:

```
<label><input /></label>
```

And the plugin expects:

```
<input /><label for=''></label>
```

Here is the modified function:

```
function createNewRadioButton(
        selector,
        newRadioBtnId,
        newRadioBtnName,
        newRadioBtnText){

    // create a new radio button using supplied parameters
    var newRadioBtn = $('<input />').attr({
        type: "radio", id: newRadioBtnId, name: newRadioBtnName
    });

    // create a new label and append the new radio button
    var newLabel = $('<label />').attr('for', newRadioBtnId).text(newRadioBtnText);

    // add the input then the label (and forget about the <br/>
    $(selector).append(newRadioBtn).append(newLabel).buttonset("refresh");
}
```

Don't forget to **initiliaze** the plugin, even if the container '#radioX' is empty:

```
$('#radioX').buttonset();
```

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/JeFWx/) for you to see a working example.

Answer (score -1):

It must be a bug. Change jQuery version from 1.7.1 to 1.8.3, choose UI in [jsfiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/JeFWx/) and you will see that it is now working as expected.

```
code here
```